# Adding a value to itself inside a while loop also, taking the final value and using it outside the loop

Tags: java, filereader, ioexception

This program is supposed to read a text file which contains these integers     -6
5
8
20
10
17
21
22
14
and then find the average.

I'm having an issue adding the value to itself inside the while loop and then using the final value of sum and using it outside the while loop.

```
public static void getAvg() throws IOException{
    File file = new File
        ("C:\\Users\\Home Pc\\Desktop\\txtfiles\\q5.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    String nextval;
    int i = 0, newvalInt,sum, avg, numofInts = 0;

    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        newvalInt = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
        sum =+ newvalInt; //<-- is this the proper way to keep adding a value to itself?
        numofInts++;
    }

    avg = sum/numofInts; // <-- gives an error , can't access the sum variable inside the while loop
    System.out.println("The average is: " + avg);
    sc.close(); 
}
```

Comment: `sum += newvalInt;`

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0

Answer (score 0):

There are three main problems

- `sum =+ newvalInt;` should be `sum += newvalInt;`
- `sum` can not be used before be initialized, so `int i = 0, newvalInt,sum = 0, avg, numofInts = 0;`
- Integer division http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0
  so cast either `sum` or `numofInts` to be a double